# Compare float in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this :

```
Offers eoResponse = eoClient.getOffers(url);
Collections.sort(eoResponse, new Comparator<Offer>() {
  public int compare(Offer offer1, Offer offer2) {
    return offer1.getAmount().compareToIgnoreCase(offer2.getAmount()); // errors in this line cannot resolve method compareToIgnoreCase(float)
  }
});
```

i want to sort my arraylist compared to prices, but i have this error :

```
 cannot resolve method compareToIgnoreCase(float)
```

what's wrong

Comment: `compareToIgnoreCase` is a `String` method. Your `getAmount()` methods return `float` primitives.

Comment: What to you expect comparing `float` values "ignoring case" to mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you probably want:

```
return Float.compare(offer1.getAmount(), offer2.getAmount());
```

That's if `getAmount()` returns a `float` - that means you won't be able to call methods on it directly, but [`Float.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-) is a handy workaround.

If `getAmount()` actually returns a `Float` (and you know it'll be non-null) you can use:

```
return offer1.getAmount(),compare(offer2.getAmount());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this method call for comparison:   `offer1.getAmount().compareTo(offer2.getAmount());`

Also you should use `Float`, and not `float` as the type for the `amount`
field in your `Offer` class. Or ... you can keep the `float` type for
`amount` and simply define the `getAmount` method to return `Float` type.
Below is a complete working example.

Your compilation error was there because the
primitive type `float` has no `compareTo` method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test002 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Offer> lst = new ArrayList<Offer>();
        lst.add(new Offer());
        lst.add(new Offer());
        lst.add(new Offer());
        lst.add(new Offer());

        lst.get(0).setAmount(10f);
        lst.get(1).setAmount(2f);
        lst.get(2).setAmount(20f);
        lst.get(3).setAmount(1f);

        Collections.sort(lst, new Comparator<Offer>() {
              public int compare(Offer offer1, Offer offer2) {
                return offer1.getAmount().compareTo(offer2.getAmount());
              }
        });

        for (int i=0; i<lst.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(lst.get(i).getAmount());
        }
    }

}

class Offer {
    private Float amount;

    public Float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Mercer OK, let me try to write an example for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like:

```
return offer1.getAmount() < offer2.getAmount() ? -1 
       : offer1.getAmount() > offer2.getAmount() ? 1 
       : 0;
```

Comment: Float.compare is a simpler way of doing this, IMO :)

Comment: @JonSkeet You are correct, I'd forgotten the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the return type of `getAmount()` is a `float`, which is a primitive and as such doesn't have any methods connected to it.

You can either change the return type of `getAmount()` to `Float`, or add a cast in the method and use `Float#compareTo`

```
public int compare(Offer offer1, Offer offer2) {
    return ((Float) offer1.getAmount()).compareTo(offer2.getAmount());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can do this way easier:

```
List<Offer> offers = eoClient.getOffers(url);
Collections.sort(offers, Comparator.comparing(Offer::getAmount));
```